# How to show UITableView Cell in UITableView without array?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have this code:

```
    class UserProfilViewController: UIViewController {
    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var userProfileTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Profil"
    }

}

// MARK: - Table View Data Source
extension UserProfilViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserProfilCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }



}
```

My project in bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/trifek/karta-nauka/src/master/

I placed one tableviewcell cell on the tableview (UserProfil.storyboard). I have a form on it that I would like to display in this cell. The problem is the cell does not display. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: "I have a form on it", is it UIView?

Comment: yes, I have storyboard UserProfil.storyboard. In this I have view with tableview and cell. This cell is invisible :(

Comment: If it is static one cell, why you are creating dynamic tableview, you can also use static cells as well

Comment: yes, it's static cell

Comment: then don't go for dynamic cells

Comment: O, i.e., delete: userProfileTableView.delegate = self, userProfileTableView.dataSource = self, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170849/discussion-between-ppl-and-lukasz-betta).

Comment: You have defined an IBOutlet for the tableView. Why not set the delegates directly in IB ? That's much simpler.

Comment: Please remove all irrelevant code from your question. e.g. what does `prefersStatusBarHidden ` have to do with the problem?

Comment: OK done. Please check it again my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code you have shared, Please change your code to following.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserProfilCell", for: indexPath) as! UserProfilTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, first try to clear your requirements. If you want to display **fix number of cells** then you can simply use **static cells**. If your cells are **dynamic** i.e their number depends on some calculation or other logic, then you can use **dynamic cell**. While using dynamic cell, verify if you have registered it or not (if you are using `xib` for cell) and also verify for the cell `identifier`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Lukasz 

    Please use the below code for this.

    class UserProfileViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
               setUIComponents()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        private func setUIComponents(){

            registerNibs()
        }
    }

    extension UserProfileViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    internal func registerNibs(){

            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing:  UserProfileTableCell.self), bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier:     kUserProfileCellReuseId)
        }

        //MARK: TableView Methods -
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return 5
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let sessionCell: UserProfileTableCell.self = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kUserProfileCellReuseId, for: indexPath) as! UserProfileTableCell.self
            cell.titleLabel.text = “TEST”
            return sessionCell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }

class UserProfileTableCell: UITableViewCell {

//Set the "kUserProfileCellReuseId" in nib to register identifier.
let kUserProfileCellReuseId = "kUserProfileCellReuseId"

//MARK: - Override Methods
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        setUIComponents()
    }

    private func setUIComponents(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never declare that your view controller conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` or `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. Given that you don't do that, you would not be able to set your view controller as the data source or delegate of your table view.